# How to refresh token with different endpoint?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth, refresh-token

I have an Ember app in which I use [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) for authentication. My backend is structure in a way that the endpoint for authorization is different from the endpoint for refreshing.

How can I specify a different endpoint for refreshing? So far, I only found [serverTokenEndpoint](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator.html#property_serverTokenEndpoint) which specifies both auth and refreshing endpoints at once.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token? It's an extension to `ember-simple-auth` that abstracts some of the token work out and includes a specific configuration for `serverTokenRefreshEndpoint`. We've been happy using it happily for years.